# How to update the app dynamically whenerver any package or library is updated in flutter apps without updating the app

Tags: react-native, flutter, package, yaml

I wanted to know that when a package or library is updated in futter ,we have to manually update the version name in pubspec file. but I want to do this without even updating the app which on play store or app store. I just want to update the app dynamically.This can be done in react native and here also it may be done in flutter. Please let me know if you have any idea

Drop your comments down and let me know

Thank you

Comment: these kind of questions are in rise i suppose, a source code is not same as the compiled byte code, converting to bytecode needs a compiler(sdk), its impossible, even if it is possible it goes against the appstore policies, a webview app is your best bet

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done in Flutter.  React Native does it by hauling around the JS compiler.  The Flutter compiler (and all the tree-shaken unreferenced classes and methods) are simply gone at release delivery time.

That's why the debug app is so much bigger than the release app.  The debug app has your code, the compiler, the hot-loader, and does no tree-shaking to remove unused classes and methods.